# clear the map built by gmapping or restart gmapping by program

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m trying to clear the map previously built by gmapping to build another place's map. I want to clear the map or restart the gmmaping node by computer programs, not manually. How can the map be cleared or the gmapping node be restarted by program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52869/clear-the-map-built-by-gmapping-or-restart-gmapping-by-program/) by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you'll have to do that manually by calling `kill/rosnode kill` and `rosrun/launch`. There is no restart functionality for ROS nodes.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1